# like function differs depending on calls R

Tags: r

The `%like%` function seems to work incorrectly for me. Do you know any possible reasons for this?

Examples:

```
> 'I' %like% 'I'
[1] TRUE
> 'Is' %like% 'I' # Should be true but is false
[1] FALSE
> 'Is' %>% like('I') # works when I call it as a function
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `%like%` from DescTools, and one from data.table.

Using the `'Is' %like% 'I'` in data.table should give TRUE. In DescTools, you are probably looking for:

`'It' %like% 'I%'` (starting with 'I')

`'It' %like% '%I%'` (contains 'I')

See below:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 2 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
> 'Is' %like% 'I'
[1] TRUE
> library(DescTools)

Attaching package: ‘DescTools’

The following object is masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    %like%

> 'Is' %like% 'I'
[1] FALSE
```